# Zapier validate method returns error

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

[image: zapier validate error]. This is the error I get when I run "zapier validate" command. My package.json file has this code :

```
"name": "github-example-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An example app for the Zapier platform.",
  "repository": "zapier/zapier-platform-app-github-example",
  "homepage": "https://zapier.com/developer",
  "author": "Zane Lyon <zane.lyon@zapier.com>",
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --recursive"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.10.0",
    "npm": ">=5.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "zapier-platform-core": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "should": "^13.2.0"
  }
```

and here is the package-lock.json code which shows the zapier-platform-core details:

```
"zapier-platform-core": {
      "version": "7.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/zapier-platform-core/-/zapier-platform-core-7.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-8nJ9xs6Dig1/Hvvpcz3upD0lnPd/gg5YCpum2S5xLnsV5yuQXUcEIXuQq7T5PPksmQgO3ux57szN4EU2+q9RvA==",
      "requires": {
        "bluebird": "3.5.0",
        "content-disposition": "0.5.2",
        "dotenv": "5.0.1",
        "form-data": "2.2.0",
        "lodash": "4.17.10",
        "node-fetch": "1.7.1",
        "zapier-platform-schema": "7.0.0"
      }
    },
```

I tried changing the package.json code as

```
"dependencies": {
        "zapier-platform-core": "^7.0.0"
      },
```

to

```
"dependencies": {
        "zapier-platform-core": "7.0.0"
      },
```

after this I get the error 
[image]
What must I do to resolve this ? This code was running fine two days back. What might have happened to cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

That error comes from [here](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli/blob/237421e467f0fe322fcbf9afecd6c1fd88c0f140/src/utils/misc.js#L108-L115) and pops up when we can't find `zapier-platform-core` in `node_modules`.

It seems like it should be there given what you posted. with `"zapier-platform-core": "7.0.0"` in your `package.json`, run `rm -rf node_modules && npm i` to make sure everything is fresh.

If that doesn't work, please open an issue at https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli/issues/new.